# Need help on crating a bash script dealing with multiple prompts for authentication

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I have a command I need to run on start up but it requires I enter the password several times and I have no idea how to make this work:

```
$ systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd && systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd && systemctl enable ntpd && systemctl start ntpd

==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: benja
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Removed /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-timesyncd.service.
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Authenticating as: benja
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to stop 'systemd-timesyncd.service'.
Authenticating as: benja
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: benja
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Authenticating as: benja
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'ntpd.service'.
Authenticating as: benja
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
```

Is this possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If authentication is read from stdin, echo it into the application with a pipe. If it is read from the tty, use the `expect` tool. Otherwise, try to configure the service to use stored authentication or use no authentication at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it all via sudo in a subshell.

```
sudo sh -c 'systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd && systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd && systemctl enable ntpd && systemctl start ntpd'
```

That way `sudo` will ask for password only once. Usually `sudo` is configured to "remember" the password, so the next time you run `sudo` it shouldn't ask for password again, so you also can:

```
sudo systemctl .. && sudo systemctl ... && sudo etc.
```